# Arc length calculation in Octave

Tags: octave

I'm trying to calculate the arc length of a 3D curve in Octave. I found a short script (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/integration-to-find-arc-length.html) and modified it to the form bellow and I get the "operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 33x1, op2 is 33x1)" error. I'm lost.

Code:

```
# calculating the length of a 3D curve
t=0:0.1:0.25*pi;
r3=81.109;
m=5;
n=20;
f=@(t) sqrt(r3^2+(t*n.^t+m*t*n.^t*log(n))^2)
len=integral(f,0,0.25*pi)
```

Comment: There are missing dots for element-wise operation in your code. It should have been: `f=@(t)sqrt(r3^2+(t.*n.^t+m*t.*n.^t*log(n)).^2)`

Comment: thanks for the solution. Could you please explain why I need to put the dot at  ....*log(n).^2). Log function doesn't include the variable t.

Comment: Please see this ([Array vs. Matrix Operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html)) documentation link. It's from Mathworks but that link is one-to-one applicable on Octave

Comment: Thanks for everything!